# Video feed from python OpenCV and Flask to Flutter using HTTP package

Tags: python, flutter, dart, http

I am trying to load a face recognition script that I coded in python using OpenCV into my flutter app that would use the local cameras of my mobile phone where my app is loaded.  I first run the python script which sends the video feed to http://127.0.0.1:5000/video_feed with Flask and then in Flutter I am trying to load the video feed from a Textbutton via the HTTP package with a get command.

However when I click the button I get no response, anyone have any idea why the http isnt loading into my flutter app?

Python Script:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +
     "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
     
def generate():
     while True:
          ret, frame = cap.read()
          if ret:
               gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
               faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
               for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
               (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
               if not flag:
                    continue
               yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
                    bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')


@app.route("/video_feed")


def video_feed():
     return Response(generate(),
          mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=False)
     #video_feed()
cap.release()
```

Here is my Flutter code of the TextButton:

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/video_feed'));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Start Detecting Faces',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
```

Comment: on further thought, the python script is running on my local PC but the flutter app is running on a physical device i have connected.  So I need to find a way to also run the python script on the device so it can be recognized from the flutter app.  Someone please help?

Comment: Why not use https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection to detect face? I think you need python script and Flask if you want to recognize the name or id of the face.

Comment: Thanks @MiftakhulArzak but I want to keep the code transferrable for detecting other objects as well.  So would still need to use openCV

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate():

        recognizer=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        recognizer.read('modeloLBPHFace.xml')
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        faceClassif=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

        while True:
            ret,frame = cap.read()
            if ret == False: break
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            auxFrame = gray.copy()
            faces=faceClassif.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

            
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                rostro = auxFrame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                rostro = cv2.resize(rostro,(200,200),interpolation= cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                # global resultado
                # print(resultado)
                resultado=recognizer.predict(rostro)

                cv2.putText(frame,'{}'.format(resultado),(x,y-5),1,1.3,(255,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

            if resultado[1] < 70:
                cv2.putText(frame,'{}'.format(imagePaths[resultado[0]]),(x,y-25),2,1.1,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
                nombre=imagePaths[resultado[0]]
                documet=resultado[0]
                print(nombre)
                with open ('Horario.csv', 'r+') as h:
                    data=h.readline()
                    listanombre=[]
                    for line in data:
                        entrada=line.split(',')
                        listanombre.append(entrada[0])
                    if nombre not in listanombre:
                        info = datetime.now()
                    fecha = info.strftime('%D')
                    hora = info.strftime("%I:%M %p")
                    h.writelines(f'\n{documet}'),
                    h.writelines(f'\n{nombre}'),
                    h.writelines(f'\n{fecha}'),
                    h.writelines(f'\n{hora}')


            else:
                cv2.putText(frame,'Desconocido',(x,y-20),2,0.8,(0,0,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)        
            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
            if not flag:
                continue
            yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
                    bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')

            k =  cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k == 27:
                break
```

Comment: Thanks but still cant get the python script to run in flutter using the http package to connect to the URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000  any idea how to connect it?

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're encountering is related to the use of np.bool8, which is a deprecated alias for np.bool_ in NumPy 1.24. To address this warning, you should modify your code to check for np.bool_ instead.